# Python and history expansion

Tags: python, linux

I'm writing a Python script which is executed on my Linux NAS and got into the interesting situation.

There is a problem accessing files/directories which start with the exclamation mark (history expansion).

```
import os
path = "/volume1/Images/!Test/DSC_5062.NEF"
os.stat(path)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/volume1/Images/!Test/DSC_5062.NEF'
```

If I try to escape the exclamation mark, I will get the following:

```
import os
path = "/volume1/Images/\!Test/DSC_5062.NEF"
os.stat(path)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/volume1/Images/\\!Test/DSC_5062.NEF'
```

Any idea what to do? By the way, the first code snippet works on my MacOS machine without any issue, but it doesn't work on my Linux NAS.

To provide complete information if I do following on the command line, I'll get the following results.

```
admin@nas:/tmp$ ls /volume1/Images/!Test/DSC_5062.NEF
-sh: !Test/DSC_5062.NEF: event not found
admin@nas:/tmp$ ls /volume1/Images/\!Test/DSC_5062.NEF
/volume1/Images/!Test/DSC_5062.NEF
```

Thanks for the help.

Michal

Comment: I've never used history expansion in this context. Regardless, I don't think it will work in the context of `os`.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with history expansion.  History expansion is done by a shell (e.g. `bash`).  Opening a file in python (or `stat`ing it) does not involve shells in any way.  There must be another problem here.

Comment: You could try pulling the dir from python and seeing what names you get. There's an actual ! in the filename right? Nothing to do with actual shell history expansion.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting it in quotes:

```
import os
path = "/volume1/Images/"'!'"Test/DSC_5062.NEF"
os.stat(path)
```

Comment: There are no extra quotes in the resulting string. You've just concatenated it together with no changes.